# Js creating issue on enter key event

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events, jquery-ui-tabs

I am trying to check some conditions on <kbd>enter</kbd> key. For that purpose I wrote some code but that code executes some other code also. I tried but not found why the issue occur. Like I have text field and I am loading data on that using ajax character search and now I am trying to add new condition that if <kbd>enter</kbd> key is pressed check the field and do some work, but it checks and send the form without clicking my submit button. I am confused why this happening. Below is my code:

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery("#name").keyup(function(event) 
    { 
        // this is code to check whether enter key is pressed or not
        if(event.keyCode == 13){
            if(jQuery('#name').val()==''){
                alert("Please select Product name First.")
                jQuery('#name').focus();
                jQuery('#name').css('border','1px solid red');
            }else{ 
                // jQuery('#checkpname').click();
                changetab('step2'); // I want to stop code after this
            }
        // this is code to check whether enter key is pressed or not
        }else{ 
            var searchid = jQuery(this).val();
            var dataString = 'search='+ searchid;
            if(searchid!='')
            {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '<?php echo Mage::helper('core/url')->getHomeUrl();?>pmembers/packages/searchproducts/key/e0603b30a8d5802f6df3jhyd87f31ddb/',
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html) {
                        jQuery("#result").html(html).show();
                    }
                });
            }   
        }
    });
    //jQuery('body').on('click', '#result',function(e){
    jQuery("#result").live("click",function(e){ 
        var $clicked = jQuery(e.target);
        // var $name = $clicked.find('.name').html();
        //var decoded = jQuery("<div>").html($name).text();
        jQuery('#name').val(jQuery(e.target).text());
    });
    jQuery(document).on("click", function(e) { 
        var $clicked = jQuery(e.target);
        if (! $clicked.hasClass("search")){
            jQuery("#result").fadeOut(); 
        }
    });
    jQuery('#name').click(function(){
        jQuery("#result").fadeIn();
    });
});
```

This is the changetab function :

```
function changetab(hrf){
    jQuery('a.btn').each(function () {
    jQuery(this).click(function () {
      //var thisid = $('#sell .tab-pane.active').attr('id');
      jQuery('.wizard a[data-toggle="tab"]').removeClass('current');
      jQuery('.wizard a[href="#'+hrf+'"]').click();
    });
  });
}
```

This function basically change tabs. I only want to check the textfield with enter if not empty then load second tab. The tab function works fine on other condition only enter creating issue. Hope someone understands what I am trying to say.

Comment: you have to `else` block following each other. why?

Comment: @Javad_Amiry if you see it my code there are two conditions one for entery key press event and one for empty textfield.both are different

Comment: You really need to work on your code formatting ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should handle key's event. But you're not. try:

```
if(event.keyCode == 13){
    event.preventDefault();
    if(jQuery('#name').val()==''){
        alert("Please select Product name First.")
        jQuery('#name').focus();
        jQuery('#name').css('border','1px solid red');
    }else{ 
        // jQuery('#checkpname').click();
        changetab('step2'); // I want to stop code after this
    }
    // I always return a false and never trust preventDefault
    return false;
// this is code to check whether enter key is pressed or not
}else{ /* rest of code */
```

And: as I remember, you can handle key's events on `keydown` event, not `keyup`. So try that. It should work.

```
jQuery("#name").keydown(function(event){ /* rest of your code... */
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding event.preventDefault() in your keycheck function which prevents its actual functionality and does what you say.

**Try event.stopPropagation() instead and let me know**

**UPDATED**

```
if(event.keyCode == 13){
     event.stopPropagation();
    if(jQuery('#name').val()==''){
    alert("Please select Product name First.")
    jQuery('#name').focus();
    jQuery('#name').css('border','1px solid red');

   }else{ 

  // jQuery('#checkpname').click();
    changetab('step2'); // I want to stop code after this
      return false;
   }
```

Add wherever you need. Check the below link for its proper functionality

[PreventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

Comment: Thanks for response.Code creates issue on else condition not here where you mentioned.like i pressed enter and textfield is not empty.However i am testing your code.

Comment: It still submits page on enter key.I want to stop execution after at the end of entery key condition.Hope you got my point.

Comment: It still submitting the form on both conditions.